# How to find the number of ways seven boys and three girls can be seated in a row if the girls sit together at one end of the row

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of ways seven boys and three girls can be seated in a
row if the girls sit together at one end of the row.

I'm struggling with the 'end of the row' part of the question.

Comment: $G_1G_2G_3B_1B_2B_3B_4B_5B_6B_7$ or $B_1B_2B_3B_4B_5B_6B_7G_1G_2G_3$

Comment: These are two possible ways. What do you need to do now to get all the possible ways ?

Comment: Do you know the binomial coefficient?

Comment: What does the binomial coefficient have to do with it, @Jacob? It's just permutations, isn't it?

Comment: Strategy:  Choose the end of the row where the girls sit, arrange the three girls in those three positions, then arrange the seven boys in the remaining seven positions.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You are more likely to get answers instead of comments if you follow the advice given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two cases, one where all the girls sit on the left hand side, and one where they all sit on the right hand side.

For the girls sitting on the LHS you'll get $G_1G_2G_3B_1B_2...B_7$ which will have $3!7!$ number of combinations.

Then you'll get the same amount of combinations with the girls all sitting on the RHS.

So then your answer should be $2\times3!7!$